# AWS API gateways CORS error when reading from post body

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have an application written in React JS, running on localhost, which makes API calls to API Gateway in AWS. API Gateway forwards requests to a lambda function, which returns a response. I have enabled CORS on AWS side.
At the moment whenever I click a 'request' button in the application I get a response from the gateway. Here is my current python code:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = {}
    response['result'] = "Success"
    response['message'] = "Updated successfully!"
    return {
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
        },
        "body": json.dumps(response)
    }
```

And here's the body of the request:

```
{
    "ID": "1101",
    "RequestDate": "2021-02-28"
}
```

This works fine. I get the 'message' value from this response and can display it without problems.
Next I want to display the information containing some data coming from the request. For example instead of `Updated successfully` I would like to get the `RequestDate` from the request and return `Updated successfully on 2021-02-28`.
I added these two lines:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    body = json.loads(event['body'])
    request_date = body['RequestDate']
    response = {}
    response['result'] = "Success"
    response['message'] = "Updated successfully!"
    return {
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
        },
        "body": json.dumps(response)
    }
```

As soon as I make this change I get the following code in my application:

```
Access to fetch at url from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This only happens when I add `request_date = body['RequestDate']`. I tried returning the body only and it was working fine as well.

In my react js application I add following headers as well:

```
async callAPI(url, method, data) {

    let result = await fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          data
        })
    })  
    return result.json().then(body => this.notify(body['message'])); 
  }
```

I tried enabling CORS and deploying the resource again but to no avail. I have added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to allowed headers in AWS. As I mentioned it works fine with post method prior to adding that one line. What could be wrong here and how can I remedy it?

EDIT:
One more thing. I get this error only from my application running on localhost. Curling or using any REST client works fine.

EDIT2:
Added fetch code

Comment: can you try returning `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*'` from lambda?

Comment: Tried now, still the same

Answer (score 0):

Setting up CORS in Lambda is dependent on how you setup API Gateway. API Gateway has several modes [REST, HTTP, WebSocket]. In the case of REST, API Gateway does some pre-processing on the incoming request like parameter validation before passing to Lambda. HTTP Proxy is just that, a pass through to Lambda, and Websockets is not really for this discussion.

I am assuming it is because you are using API Gateway in standard configuration and you have not [enabled CORS on API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html). The code you provided above will work for API Gateway Configured for HTTP.

If you are using the [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-apigateway-readme.html), or CloudFormation then you must configure CORS there, else the easiest is to use the console.

Go to your API in the AWS Console, select resources, select your method or service, from the actions menu enable CORS. And then publish your updated API.

[image]

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html) is a link to the AWS documentation that outlines how to do it.

Some advice, when testing endpoints via a browser it is best not to use Localhost or 127.0.0.1 it has unintended consequences. [Edit your hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) and give yourself a domain name, and use that domain name instead.

CORS is there for a reason to prevent [Cross Site Scripting or Cross Site Origin Attacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Try not to use *, testing sure, but production no. If you have code say on S3, and your REST services on say API Gateway you can front both with CloudFront using the same Origin, and let CloudFront know to forward based on URL (e.g /API) to APIGateway and the other to S3. Thus everything has the same domain.

Comment: I have enabled CORS as described in your answer. At the moment I simply need this to work, I don't need to worry about security.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have on my server and it works fine. Using fetch on the front-end.

Server Code:

```
import json
result = {"hello": "world"}
return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        'body': json.dumps(result)
    }
```

Front-end Code using ES6

```
url = "Your url"
path = "Your desired path"
data = {"hello": "world"}
const response = await fetch(url + path, {
  method: "POST",
  cache: "no-cache",
  mode: "cors",
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

Comment: What you posted works for me as well. The error occurs when I try to read any data from the request received by the server. Adding `body = json.loads(event['body'])
    request_date = body['RequestDate']` is what breaks it. Have you tried getting any data from the request and displaying it?

Comment: I I imagine you are not including "RequestDate" in your fetch request. Can you share your fetch request code? 
Also, you are getting the CORS error because your function is failing to execute and returning an error message. Put it inside a `try: except:` block to prevent it.

Comment: I added the fetch code. "RequestDate" is included. As soon as I comment out "request_date = body['RequestDate']" on the server side I stop getting the error and get a proper response but then I cannot add the date from the request to the response.

Answer (score 0):

Add statusCode inside response from lambda

```
return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
        },
        'body': json.dumps(response)
    }
```

In case there is any error in your lambda it will return default 5XX response without any CORS headers and in such cases browser will complain for cors headers not found.

You can add your current code in `try` block and in `except` block you can print the error and return some default response like below

```
return {
        'statusCode': 500,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST'
        },
        'body': json.dumps({'message':'Unexpected error'})
    }
```

Add some log statements in your lambda and check api gateway configuration for Lambda proxy setting.

Make sure you check your api gateway logs and lambda function logs for some more details regarding error.